# Object not found! error when I want using route in php

Tags: php

I'm watching a tutorial video from youtube about making simple route project with just php and I did exactly what he did but there is an error in my project and I can't fix that . when I'm trying to write 'about' or 'contact' the webpage went to object not found! error

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL 
manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.5
```

by the way I'm using xampp

This is my route class

```php
class Route{

    private $_uri = array();

    /**
     * Builds a collection of internal URL's to look for
     * @param $uri
     */
    public function add($uri){
        $this->_uri[] = trim($uri,"/");
    }
    public function submit(){

        $uriGetParam = isset($_GET['uri']) ? $_GET['uri'] : "/";

        foreach ($this->_uri as $key => $value){
            if (preg_match("#^$value$#",$uriGetParam)){
                echo "Match!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my php code (index)

```
include "route.php";

$route = new Route();

$route->add("/");
$route->add("/contact");
$route->add("/about");

$route->submit();
```

And finally this is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /route/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I think you need to call `$route->submit();` at the end of your index.php file

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes I forgot that . But the problem is that I can't got to any url . the tutors of that tutorial inserted a wrong url and the website jumped to home automatically . but i just have object not found !!

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What's the exact URL triggering the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase as i use  xampp . the default url for my project is localhost/myproject/route/ so i add 'about' after the last / -> localhost/myproject/route/about

Comment: Have you tried checking whether `RewriteBase` is somehow flawed? I would assume the tutorial you are following does not use `myproject`?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes it's correct . I should write /myproject/route/ . Thank you I've been struggling with this problem for 2 days